# Need PID of current process, getpid() returns -1

Tags: c++, linux, unix, process

I need to come up with a unique name for a file used by a process (executing my C++ program). Before I used a static string, but when I tried to run two instances of the program in parallel, I realized they were both accessing the same file.

To this end, I would like the file name to include the PID of the process that creates and is using it.

However, when I try to use `getpid()`, I always seem to get `-1` as the return value.

```
void accessfile(){
   std::cout << "DEBUG: accessfile() called by process " << getpid() << " (parent: " << getppid() << ")" << std::endl;
   // Code here to create and/or access the file
}
```

When I run this, I get:

```
DEBUG: accessfile() called by process -1 (parent: 17565)
```

I checked `ps ux` and the process `17565` is actually my login shell. How do I get the PID of the program I'm currently executing?

I did notice this bit of information in the manual entry for `getpid()`:

```
   Since glibc version 2.3.4, the glibc wrapper function for getpid()
   caches PIDs, so as to avoid additional system calls when a process
   calls getpid() repeatedly.  Normally this caching is invisible, but
   its correct operation relies on support in the wrapper functions for
   fork(2), vfork(2), and clone(2): if an application bypasses the glibc
   wrappers for these system calls by using syscall(2), then a call to
   getpid() in the child will return the wrong value (to be precise: it
   will return the PID of the parent process).  See also clone(2) for
   discussion of a case where getpid() may return the wrong value even
   when invoking clone(2) via the glibc wrapper function.
```

Indeed I am using glibc 2.4. I understand that using `getpid()` without a corresponding `fork()` may cause an issue, but I don't see the behavior they describe. `getppid()` correctly gets the parent PID (the login shell), but yet the return value of `getpid()` doesn't seem to make sense.

Can anyone shed light on why it returns -1 (can't find any documentation that details what this return value means), and also how I might be able to get the process ID? Do I need to just fork a dummy process *just* to get the current process ID? Thanks!

Comment: The `getpid()` call isn't supposed to be able to fail, or return a negative PID.  The `glibc` wrapper sounds broken to me; I guess it isn't, but frankly the wrapper sounds like more trouble than it is worth.  Dammit, if I call `getpid()`, I want the PID of my process regardless of how it was created.  (POSIX [`getpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpid.html)
 says: _The `getpid()` function shall return the process ID of the calling process._ and also _The `getpid()` function shall always be successful and no return value is reserved to indicate an error._

Comment: What OS you are using (including version)? Also make sure that you do not override system function `getpid()` with some wrapper, macro etc in your project.

Comment: Distro: `CentOS release 4.8 (Final)`, Kernel: `Linux 2.6.9-89.ELlargesmp #1 SMP Mon Jun 22 12:46:58 EDT 2009`

Comment: Write a minimum program in c++ that just prints current pid to the cout. Do not use any of your libraries etc. What does it output?

Comment: @Slava -- someone added a method `getpid()` to return the `pid_t` data member of some class we have... I would have never thought to check that. Thank you very much for the insight.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you call system functions in C++ it is a good idea to explicitly use their namespace (global one in this case):

```
void accessfile(){
   std::cout << "DEBUG: accessfile() called by process " << ::getpid() << " (parent: " << ::getppid() << ")" << std::endl;
   // Code here to create and/or access the file
}
```

And it shows why it is a bad idea to use `using namespace std;` construction

Comment: VS2017 compiler warning C4996: 'getpid': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _getpid.